# Retrieving user-uploaded images from filesystem for display in Flask template

Tags: python, image, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask

I'm wiring up a website which allows my client to create a item listing, then upload images of the item. What I need is a way of associating the images with their respective metadata. After extensive StackOverflow browsing and Google-fu, I've yet to come across a specific solution, only vague references that filesystem storage is better than BLOB storage.

So, as it stands, I naturally have a `User` object and a `Listing` object which can have several associated images, including a "default" image. Listing has a handful of attributes like `listing.id`, `listing.title`, `listing.body`, etc.

Some info: I'm using Python (Flask), Postgresql, and SQLAlchemy.

### My initial approach.

I started off with the idea that I would upload the image files to Flask's static directory, with the basic structure of:

```
static/
  images/
    category_1/
      listing_1/           # based on the DB id
        default.jpg        # renamed server-side to represent default view of item
        random_string.jpg  # renamed to avoid naming collisions
        random_string.gif  # renamed to avoid naming collisions
      listing_2/
        default.jpg
        random_string.png
    category_2/
      # etc.
```

This way I could simply construct the path to the file based the `listing.id`. This has a problem though: I've allowed the extensions `.png`, `jpg`, `.jpeg`, and `.gif`. To display the default representation in a template, then, something like a

```
glob.glob(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], listing.category, str(listing.id), 'default*'))
```

or a convoluted `if/elif/elif/else` is necessary. That means something like (pseudocode):

```
for listing in listings:
  ext = rsplit_of_glob(listing.id)
  listing.ext = ext
```

And now things start to look murkier. Which leads me to

### My second approach.

I could keep the same directory structure (unless anyone has any objections), but store the paths to the images as a list in the database. It would solve any problems with errant extensions or some future off-by-one problem I can't see right now.

Unfortunately, if I store the full path, it introduces the problem that now everything will be hardcoded. I was trying to avoid that. So my compromise is to add an images column in each `listing` row in the database, but only include the images' filenames + extensions. This way I can create the path based on the `listing.id`, and still have all the requisite information.

### The real question.

Is either of these solutions on the right path, or am I missing something entirely? Forgive my naiveté. I'd also like to know what the best way of storing image-specific metadata (e.g., upload timestamp) for each image is. Something tells me creating an image table/SQLAlchemy image object is overkill. Would a storing a pickled Python dictionary of metadata in each `listing` row suffice?

I realize this is a large question, and possibly subject to being closed for its somewhat open-ended nature, but any help would be appreciated. There may be no canonical answer, but something tells me there has to be a best-practices way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: What you're doing seems sensible enough. (codereview.stackexchange.com exists for stuff like this, but I don't know how widely used it is.)

Comment: We are all Craig Ringer.

Comment: @CraigRinger, thanks for the tip about codereview.

Comment: +1 for an excellently put together question. I have flagged it for migration to [codereview.se], as I think it's best suited for that site.

Comment: @SeanVieira Appreciate you doing that; I'm a little hands-off on SO and I'm not sure how to migrate it myself (if it's possible at all).